To buy some pastries/baked goods/bakery products
Hello: which one of the following expressions is the most idiomatic? I made them up myself. Thank you!

To buy some pastries
To buy some baked goods, or
To buy some bakery products


It would depend on what part of the world you are in.

And whether you are referring to baked goods in general or a particular kind. "I'm going to buy some cakes/fruit tarts/Danish pastries/etc. for tea".

All of those utterances are oddly formal for something said to a friend or acquaintance. I'd say 'I'm going to buy some cakes'. 2 and 3 are especially strange for a casual conversation.

What exactly are you going to buy?

baked good and products sounds business-y. Not like a consumer talking...


which one of the following expressions is the most idiomatic?

It depends…
Pastries are usually small types of cakes that often have flaky layers and  contain fillings such as  crème pâtissière (pastry cream); whipped cream, custard; fruit etc. Think of eclairs, croissants, mille-feuille, profiteroles, jam tarts, strudel, and cannoli. There are also a few savoury pastries such as pigs in blankets or sausage rolls in the UK, vol au vents, and phyllo meat pies.
Baked goods can be either sweet or savoury products that have been baked in an oven. These would include all different types of breads, e.g. bagels; savoury or sweet pie dishes with a bottom crust e.g egg & bacon flan (a less elaborate version of quiché Lorraine), with only a top crust or completely encased in pastry, e.g. chicken pot pie, apple pie, empanada etc. as well as sweet leavened foods such as sponge cakes.
Bakery products  are baked goods that are typically sold in a bakery shop, these would include breads, pastries, and deep-fried doughs such as doughnuts (donuts US)  and angel-wings (also known as chiacchiere (Italy) and fattigmann in Norway.)
(a) I'm buying/going (out) to buy some pastries  OK
(b) … to buy some baked goods  (why are you being vague?)
(c) … to buy some bakery products  (idem)

I'm getting some pastries / some bread / some glazed donuts ✅


To echo Michael's comment "Baked goods" or "Bakery products" seems oddly formal: a useful heading in a financial spreadsheet.
Cakes are baked, but aren't made of pastry.  Some types of cheesecake are neither baked nor made of pastry.  How pedantic do you want to be.
The meanings of the words overlap and have fuzzy edges. The choice of word is likely to depend on what you actually plan to buy, but the context isn't so strict, so it probably doesn't matter.

That was me, not the admirable Kate!
